# how to handle json data in ajax request in angular.js

Tags: json, ajax, angularjs, header

I am using angular.js. And I am making an ajax request and getting response like this ...

Http Response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Mon, 26 Oct 2015 06:37:40 GMT

{"status":1}
```

but angular js is not able to parse the json data automatically. But when I return only {"status":1} in response, it works fine. I think when we send header angular should detect json automatically.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code......

Comment: this is the code in angularjs for ajax request.

` 

$http({
                   method : 'post',
                   url:'index.php',
                   /*responseType : 'json',*/

                   data : {},

            }).then($scope.successfn,$scope.errorfn);


$scope.successfn = function(response){
            var data = response.data;
            if(data.status == 0){
                alert('Error , please try again.');
            }else{
                alert('Saved successfully.');
            }
        }
        $scope.errorfn = function(){alert('Error');}

`

Comment: @KhalidHussain Sorry for unformatted code :)